# Cannot read property of undefined, but property DOES exist

Tags: react-native, expo

I have json of this format:

```
{
  "id": 18,
  "goal": {
    "name": "Test"
  }
}
```

I have this json saved in storage using [MMKV](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-mmkv). I'm passing the ID (`18` in this case) from Page1 to Page2, retrieving the json on Page2 and trying to display the `name` from the json.

However, I keep getting the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

But I have no idea why when the property exists!

Here is my Page2:

```
export default function Page2() {
  const [json, setJson] = useState({} as any);

  const { id } = useLocalSearchParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (id) {
      const jsonRecords = storage.getString('records')
      const records = JSON.parse(jsonRecords || '{}');
      const record = records.find((record: any) => record.id == id);

      console.log(record); <-- It's printing the json just fine here, as I showed above
      
      setJson(record);
    }
  }, [id]);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Text>{json.goal.name}</Text> <-- Fails on this line
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

The weird thing is, if I do this it works, but I don't understand why:

```
export default function Page2() {
  const [json, setJson] = useState({} as any);
  const [name, setName] = useState(null);

  const { id } = useLocalSearchParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (id) {
      const jsonRecords = storage.getString('records')
      const records = JSON.parse(jsonRecords || '{}');
      const record = records.find((record: any) => record.id == id);

      console.log(record); <-- It's printing the json just fine here, as I showed above
      
      setJson(record);
      setName(record.goal.name); <-- Setting name here
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Text>{name}</Text> <-- This works
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because React Native renders the component **before** the useEffect finishes. Here is the steps when React Native renders your page.

1. `json` state is defined as {}
2. Render starts before useEffect finishes, component displays `{}.goal.name` <= ***Error Occurs***
3. UseEffect finished, `json` state is updated

To fix the issue, you can use [Optional Chaining](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining) to access object property safely. It will check whether intermediate nodes exist or not  before access the property.

E.g. `<Text>{json?.goal?.name}</Text>`